# convert DD-MM-YYYY to datetype in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a date (actually a string) in the format

> DD-MM-YYYY 00:00:00

I want the datepart of that ( I don't care what format, I just need it to become a datetype)
What would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess this does the trick: select

```
convert(date,left(enddate, charindex(' ',enddate)),103)
```

Comment: this works perfect. funny thing is, and i don't know why, if i use format 103 , 104 or 105, i always get "yyyy-mm-dd" format in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DTString   varchar(20) = '19-05-2020 09:30:00'

SET @DTString   =   CONVERT(varchar(10), @DTString)     --  Get Datepart    (DD-MM-YYYY)

-- There is no implicit conversion from astring to date.
-- CONVERT won't work in that format. We need it in MM=DD-YYYY format.

DECLARE @Day        varchar(02) 
DECLARE @Month      varchar(02) 

SET @Day        =   LEFT(@DTString, 2)                  --  Get the Day
SET @Month      =   SUBSTRING(@DTString, 4, 2)          --  Get the Month

                --  STUFF(String to be modified , start position    , number of chars to deleted    , String to insert)
SET @DTString   =   STUFF(@DTString             , 1                 , 2                             , @Month)       --  Insert the Month at position 1, deleting 2 (the day  )
SET @DTString   =   STUFF(@DTString             , 4                 , 2                             , @Day  )       --  Insert the Day   at position 4, deleting 2 (the month)

SELECT @DTString    -- Here the transformation from DD-MM-YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY

SELECT CONVERT(date, @DTString) -- Now we can convert
```